# Tightvnc session with Xubuntu suddenly refuses to accept mouse/keyboard strokes

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, vnc

Server is Ubuntu 20.04 aarch64, TightVNC Server version 1.3.10, Xubuntu 20.04 desktop packages.

No anything about errors in vnc server log file, but in /var/log/syslog there were entries:

```
org.xfce.ScreenSaver[50224]: Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1".
```

Reconnection to the server doesn't help, only option is to kill existing VNC session and start new one.

Answer (score 2):

As I found out, problem was that Xubuntu tried to run screensaver and after that session did not accept any mouse/keyboard events from the client (tried remmina and xtigervncviewer).

Probably it is enough just to switch workstation into "Presentation mode" in power entry of the taskbar, but I also removed screensavers:

```
apt purge gnome-screensaver xfce4-screensaver
```